# Render different tables in a view based on years

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I am trying to make a view that renders different html tables for different years.

The model used for the view is this:

```
public class VisualizzaFattureViewModel
    {
        public FileInfo FatturaFile { get; set; }    
        public int Year { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the controller action:

```
public ActionResult VisualizzaFatture()
        {
            DirectoryInfo fattureFilesDirectory = null;
            FileInfo[] fattureFiles = null;

            try
            {
                string fattureFilesPath = Server.MapPath("~/Documents/Fatture/");
                fattureFilesDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(fattureFilesPath);
                fattureFiles = fattureFilesDirectory.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException exp)
            {
                throw exp;
            }
            catch (IOException exp)
            {
                throw exp;
            }

            fattureFiles = fattureFiles.OrderByDescending(f => f.Name).ToArray();

            List<VisualizzaFattureViewModel> fatture = new List<VisualizzaFattureViewModel>();
            foreach (var file in fattureFiles)
            {
                var model = new VisualizzaFattureViewModel();
                model.FatturaFile = file;
                model.Year = int.Parse(fattureFiles.First().Name.Split('_').ElementAt(1));
                fatture.Add(model);
            }

            return View(fatture);
```

I would like the view to display data this way for example:

```
    [2016]
    |--------------------------------------|
    |file5.name                            |
    |--------------------------------------|    

    [2015]
    |--------------------------------------|
    |file4.name                            |
    |--------------------------------------|
    |file3.name                            |
    |--------------------------------------|

    [2013]
    |--------------------------------------|
    |file2.name                            |
    |--------------------------------------|
    |file1.name                            |
    |--------------------------------------|
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should redefine your model to contain info for tables as you've described. Something like:

```
// Dictionary key is the year
// Dictionary value is a list of FileInfo structures for that year
public class VisualizzaFattureViewModel
{
    public Dictionary<int, List<FileInfo>> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And then fill model items for parsed years:

```
var model = new VisualizzaFattureViewModel();
model.Items = new Dictionary<int, List<FileInfo>>();
foreach (var file in fattureFiles)
{
    var year = int.Parse(file.Name.Split('_').ElementAt(1));
    if (!model.Items.ContainsKey(year))
    {
        model.Items.Add(year, new List<FileInfo>());
    }
    model.Items[year].Add(file);
}
return View(model);
```

In your view you then just make two foreach statements to iterate first through years, and then through every year's items and build table tags accordingly. You can also first sort dictionary by year descending if you like (since this is how you've shown it in example table).

Hope it helps. If you also need a view sample, please let me know.

Comment: You should change 
`var year = int.Parse(fattureFiles.First().Name.Split('_').ElementAt(1));`
with this
`var year = int.Parse(file.Name.Split('_').ElementAt(1));`

Comment: Arrghhh. ;) You are correct. I wasn't paying attention when doing copy paste. Thank you. Corrected my answer also.

Comment: `if (!model.Items.ContainsKey(year))  { model.Items.Add(year, new List<FileInfo>());  }`  its unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

in `ActionResult`:

```
return View(fattureFiles.ToList());
```

in `View`:

```
@model List<FileInfo>

@foreach (var item in Model.GroupBy(x => x.Name.Split('_').ElementAt(1)).OrderByDescending(x => x.Key))
{
    <h5>@item.Key</h5>
    <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach (var file in item)
        {
            <li class="list-group-item">@file.Name</li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

### OR

use your model but change it:

```
public class VisualizzaFattureViewModel
{
    public FileInfo[] FatturaFiles { get; set; }    
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

and in `ActionResult`:

```
var grp = fattureFiles.GroupBy(f => f.Name.Split('_').ElementAt(1));

var fatture = grp.Select( x=> new VisualizzaFattureViewModel() {Year = x.Key, FatturaFiles = x.ToArray() }).ToList();

return View(fatture);
```

the View:

```
@model List<VisualizzaFattureViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model.OrderByDescending(x => x.Year))
{
    <h5>@item.Year</h5>
    <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach (var file in item.FatturaFiles)
        {
            <li class="list-group-item">@file.Name</li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```